# Why does Flow fail to refine by my action type using a string discriminator?

Tags: flowtype

I'm writing a Reducer in a Redux application using Flow. My reducer action expects two kinds of actions, `NumberAction` or `StringAction`.

A `NumberAction` has a `numberValue` property, while a `StringAction` has a `stringValue` property. And, being Redux actions, they both have a `type` property, being either `NUMBER_ACTION` or `STRING_ACTION`, respectively. I test `action.type` to determine the kind of action being processed in a `switch` statement.

The way I understand [the documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions), this should be sufficient for Flow to determine the type of the `action`. However, it does not give me an error when I try to access a property that is not present on the given action type. Full code:

```
// @flow
export type NumberAction = {|
    type : 'NUMBER_ACTION',
    numberValue : number
|}

export type StringAction = {|
    type : 'STRING_ACTION',
    stringValue : string
|}

type Action = | NumberAction | StringAction;

export default function my(action : Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'NUMBER_ACTION' : {
            let value : number = action.numberValue;
            console.log("value = ", value);
            break;
        }
        case 'STRING_VALUE' : {
            let value : number = action.numberValue; // This should error, because StringAction doesn't have a numberValue property
            console.log("value = ", value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I not given an error when I in the `STRING_VALUE` case try to access `action.numberValue`?

However, if I use integers as action identifiers, I'm given the expected error:

```
// @flow
export type NumberAction = {|
    type : 1, // Note: number
    numberValue : number
|}

export type StringAction = {|
    type : 2, // Note: number
    stringValue : string
|}

type Action = | NumberAction | StringAction;

export default function my(action : Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 1 : {
            let value : number = action.numberValue;
            console.log("value = ", value);
            break;
        }
        case 2 : {
            let value : number = action.numberValue; // This errors: Flow: property `numberValue`. Property not found in object type. 
            console.log("value = ", value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I not supposed to use strings as type discriminators this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug in Flow 0.48.0.

The problem is gone when updating to Flow 0.49.1.